# How do you use modify the color definitions for a Google Calendar to allow custom colors for events?

Tags: api, events, colors, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to create new events. It appears the only method to assign a color to an event is with a colorID (1 to 11) that looks up the specific color from the table.

The default 11 color palette isn't exactly ideal for my needs so I would like to change it but I haven't been able to figure out how. The documentation explains [how to obtain](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors#resource) these lookup tables and but I can't figure out how to modify them. I assume they can be modified as there is a timestamp in the structure for the last time it was modified.

Anybody know how to modify the colorID table for events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but the answer to the question is that you can't edit the set Event colors. The new custom colors in the new API only correlate with the Calendar color itself, not the Events contained within.

Why Google would only make some of the colors customizable, and not all beats me. Until they realize the desire for more colors it would appear we are stuck with good ol' 1-11.

Answer (score 1):

Added detail from bounty:

> I have the same question. I would like to be able to set a custom color for events that I post to the calendar, but don't want to be
>   limited by the 11 choices. I see in the docs they have added an
>   additional color setting method
>   (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/whats-new#custom_colors_f‌​or_calendars).
>   But I'm unclear on the concept of how to go about it.

This part of the documentation demonstrates these properties directly: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert

Which will let you add and modify your personal calendar as a demo (scroll to the bottom and try out the API Explorer). To do what you are asking on here, set `colorRgbFormat=true` then add the `backgroundColor` or `foregroundColor` properties with the specified color.

You end up with a request which looks like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?colorRgbFormat=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
"id": "SomeCalendarItem",
"backgroundColor": "#444444"
}
```

Note: I think this answers the bounty question - which is different from what the OP asked, but might be what the OP wanted - @Wescotte, please advise if this solves (or doesn't) your issue as well.

Comment: Hmm.  when I try it like this:  POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?fields=description&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
 
{
 "id": "foocolor",
 "backgroundColor": "#0066ff"
}  I get an error response 404 resource not found.  404 Not Found
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }

Comment: Did you put your API key in? If doing it on the page did you click the `Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0` switch while logged in with a google account?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the toggle to use authorized requests and gave it the permission it wanted.